# Не могу перехватить изменения в массиве

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/VasyOk/YfqVW/

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.collection = [1545454,489465165];
App.Controller = Ember.Object.create({
    addElement: function() { console.log('add');
        App.collection.push((new Date).getTime());
                            console.log(App.collection);
    },
    changed: function(){
        $("#log").append("<p>changed</p>");
    }.observes("App.collection.@each")
});
```

Вроде бы как бы массив наполняется, но не отрабатывает метод changed, не могу понять почему :(

Comment: А почему нельзя использовать colletions как свойство App.Controller ?

Comment: да ничего не изменится

Comment: и при добавлении элемента в массив он рендерится?

Comment: нет, не редерился

Comment: по идее должен. Если через set записывать новый массив, до DOM должен измениться

Comment: @VasyOk, пожалуйста, оформите решение в качестве ответа, чтобы Вы могли получить заслуженную репутацию. Если Вы не успеете сделать это до 09.08, я оформлю ответ в качестве общего (за него не начисляется репутация) - это необходимо для улучшения структуризации содержимого сайта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел через `Ember.ArrayController`. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/VasyOk/YfqVW/5/)